# Mechanism to Constantly Check HTTP Endpoint (every 10 seconds) using Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

Lets say there's an external HTTP Endpoint (REST based) which is updating its data every ten seconds.

How to create a mechanism using Java 1.7 and Spring MVC for REST (this is not Spring Boot) that constantly calls the Endpoint and returns the results?

Is there an API to use to do this?

e.g.

Call a proper HTTP GET request

```
https://api.app.com/v1/exchangeRates/Europe?name=acme_company
```

returns:

```
{ "name" : "acme_company", "price" : "20 EUR"}
```

but the price changes every 10 seconds?

What options are out there to use when using Java 1.7 and Spring 4?

Comment: Could you give a little more information about your use case. You have a web application that provides some other services and within that application you want to update some internal database with the information this external endpoint provides every 10 secs? Basically what are you doing getting that information every 10 secs?

Comment: Yes, I have a middle tier which is REST based (Java & Spring 4)... Have a use case where have to access an external API every ten seconds where I might store in the database and / or publish stateless data to an internal  web socket.

Answer (score 1):

Spring provides an @Scheduled annotation

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate=5000)
public void doSomething() {
    // something that should execute periodically
}
```

More information [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).